# Not able to locate the dropdown value using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select the value from dropdown.

Currently I am able to click on dropdown but not able to select the value from the dropdown. Below are the code which I am using for selecting the value from the dropdown.

```
                temp.click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Select clickThis = new Select(temp); 
                try{

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    clickThis.selectByValue("India");

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("<><><><><>Not Found<><><><><><>");
                }
```

I am working it in framework, can you please let me know the code accordingly. Please check the below code which I am using.

```
private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
        boolean testCaseStep = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
            WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                temp.sendKeys(value);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                temp.click();
            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                temp.isDisplayed();

            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("clickDropdown")) {

                temp.click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Select clickThis = new Select(temp); 
                try{

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    clickThis.selectByValue("India");

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("<><><><><>Not Found<><><><><><>");
                }
               }

            testCaseStep = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"
                    + e.getMessage());

            // Take screenshot if any testcase is not working. 
            System.out.println("Taking Screen Shot");
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\workspace for selenium\\Simple page creator\\Snapshot\\screenshot.jpeg")); 
        }

        return testCaseStep;
    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;

        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }
        return temp;

    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="billing_country" name="billing_country">
<option value="">Choose Country</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="AG">Algeria</option>
<option value="AQ">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AN">Andorra</option>
<option value="AO">Angola</option>
<option value="AV">Anguilla</option>
<option value="AY">Antarctica</option>
<option value="AC">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AM">Armenia</option>
<option value="AA">Aruba</option>
<option value="AT">Ashmore and Cartier</option>
<option value="AS">Australia</option>
<option value="AU">Austria</option>
<option value="AJ">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BF">The Bahamas</option>
<option value="BA">Bahrain</option>
<option value="FQ">Baker Island</option>
<option value="BG">Bangladesh</option>
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing some unnecessary works there. Why do not you simply rely on `Select ` class to do all of those?

Comment: @Saifur Sorry not getting you can you please elaborate it or give the sample code for making it possible.

Comment: First of all, are you trying to select an option depending on value?

Comment: @Saifur Simply I want to click on dropdown, once we click on dropdown it displayed the dropdown list. Now from the dropdown list I want to select the value as "India". Current scenario is it displayed the dropdown list after clicking on dropdown, but not able to select the value "India" from the dropdown list.

Comment: Can you provide the `html` of that dropdown then?

Comment: @Saifur I have edited it, please have a look its an country dropdown list.

Comment: Please try **@Saifur** 's answer. That will get your job done. Moreover, after checking your code I suspect you are under the impression that the `innerText` India is to be used for `selectByValue` method. But, actually, it's the `value` attribute that needs to be used. For instance, if you want to select **Bahrain** above the code should be `clickThis.selectByValue("BA");`. In case you want to use `Bahrain` so there is a method `selectByVisibleText` which you can use like this `clickThis.selectByVisibleText("Bahrain");`. You can conjure up the same thing for option `India`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have numerous mix up of different kind of waits which should not be done. To find an element and check it's existence the explicit wait works most of the case. Mixing up `thread.sleep` and `implicit` wait will give you some really bad performance of test execution

Second, finding dropdown using `Select` class is the best. You can do the following which is simple and easy to debug as well.

```
By element = driver.findElement(By.id("billing_country"));
Select foo = new Select(element);
foo.selectByValue("AF"); //should select Afghanistan. I do not see India
```

See the API doc [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

Comment: I have tried with this code temp.click(); Select clickThis = new Select(temp); clickThis.selectByValue("India"); previously according to my framework. But its not working for me.

Comment: Yes, Its working fine now and I understand what the mistake I've did well thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1):

Looking by the HTML code,I assume **India** is the text of the option like below:

```
<option value="IN">India</option>
```

For this scenario please try with the following code similar to Saifur's reply but with different method.

```
By element = driver.findElement(By.id("billing_country"));
Select foo = new Select(element);
foo.selectByVisibleText("India");
```

If you want to go with your framework, please share the exception webdriver throws. As the country list is too big, option India may not be visible for the webdriver to click and would have thrown exception similar as:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (XXX, YYY). Other element would receive the click:

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("billing_country")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='billing_country']//*[contains(., 'India')]")).click();
```

Try this.  See if it works.  You could substitute the '*'s out for the actual tags, but I don't see a reason for that unless your id of "billing_country" exists elsewhere.

edit:

As mentioned elsewhere, you may need to ensure the item is clickable before actually clicking it, in which case, you can use javascript to scroll the item into view.

Answer (score 0):

In your html, `<option value="IN">India</option>` should be for India.

You have : `clickThis.selectByValue("IN");`

If you try `clickThis.selectByVisibleText("India");` t will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='billing_country']//*[contains(., 'India')]")).click();
```

By using this test-case was able to select only one value and in case if I have given another value instead of "India" but it was taking India itself, Please let me know if any corrections to this test-case